# classifying twitter messages into positive and negative tweets

Tags: java

Im a second year electronic engineering student and i have this second year project about data mining of twitter messages and to be honest I haven't got any idea of how to do it!! all i have discovered is that i need first to get the tweets and i found many websites which can do that for me, the best one was tweetarchivist.com which allows me to save my results as xls file, the problem which Im struggling with now is the data mining process and for that i decided to develop an idea which i have seen it online in several websites which is classifying specific tweets (e.g., movie) into positive and negative according to some keywords but i don't know how to do that.. i read some information about using "python and NLTK (Naive bayesian classifier)" but honestly i know nothing about Python language or any other language except java (the basic commands only) .. so please could anyone help me and suggest a good and easy data mining tool that can perform what i want ?? 
I haven't got much time so if u have any clue about that please post it and i will be very grateful !!

Comment: This is a bad SO post on many levels, particularly its laziness, but mayyyy be more appropriate for programmers.stackexchange.com. Though not in its current form.

Comment: I had a contract position at a start up, that never got off the ground doing this. It proved to be very difficult. The company went in a different direction before I was able to make any real progress. The problem comes in when you introduce sarcasm and negating words (not). They completely change the way the sentence is read. The NLTK is great tool that I utilized, but there is a lot of lot behind this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a place to start [(link to pdf file)](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/courses/cs224n/2009/fp/3.pdf). The authors get pretty far with a simple Naive Bayes classifier. Hope you weren't planning on finishing this tonight...

Anyway, happy coding!

Comment: I actually have a week to finish it .. I have read this paper before but there isn't much information about the coding !!

Comment: Oh I see. The question is tagged inappropriately. Go download RapidMiner or Weka. You don't need Python.

Comment: yeah Im sorry I'm new to this, I have downloaded WEKA and Im not really sure if WEKA is capable of doing what i want (classifying into positive and negative tweets) and beside i have read that WEKA isn't that good for text mining !!

Comment: See page 8 of that paper. They used Weka's SVM functionality---you should probably start there and try to reproduce their results.

Comment: I have looked at it .. but they didn't really show the steps of doing that and this is another problem since Im new to WEKA ..